# exclude option in selectField (ForeignKey)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

i have a user field in my model,

```
class result(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    doc_analis = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUsers, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

in database table "MyUsers" - 10 users.

How to exclude some of this 10 users from choise option in form (by id or name)?

form (view.py)

```
class ResultNew(CreateView):
    model = result
    fields = '__all__'
    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.helper = FormHelper()
        form.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Create', css_class='btn-primary'))
        form.fields['doc_change'].label = "Change"
        form.fields['doc_analis'].label = "Analysis"
        form.fields['user'].label = "Username"  # FK (10 users) 
        return form
```

Comment: Do you mean like a condition? (for example exclude `MyUsers` where `is_admin=True`?

Comment: Yes? like a condition (exclude MyUsers where user.name = 'Andrew'  or user.id = '1' )

Answer (score 0):

You need to overwrite the Form `init` method to exclude the users from the dropdown. I am assuming here that you want to exclude the users who are not `active`, but you can exclude the users based on your condition.

```
from django import forms
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['myuser'].queryset = self.fields['myuser'].queryset.exclude(is_active=False)
```

Comment: im getting an error: string indices must be integers   self.fields['user'].queryset = self.fields['user'].queryset.exclude(id=2)

Comment: try `self.fields['user'].queryset = MyUsers.objects.all().exclude(id=2)`